# jquery, my animate function doesn't work with visibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, visibility

I have an image with this class:

```
.hide{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

and when the mouse is over a div .test I want visibility to be "visible" and I also want to animate it, so I'm using

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').animate({visibility:'visible'},300);
});
```

unfortunatly it's not working.

And also I don't want to use hide() and show()

Comment: create it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visibility is not a value that you can animate, it is like a boolean for hidden/visible.

Why not try with opacity instead ?

http://jsfiddle.net/PqypU/1/

```
.hide{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: "old-ie-staff";
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').animate({opacity: 1},300);
});
```